# how to redirect and seprate out the server response in php curl

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, curl

i am working with cURL and got the API response in xml but browser in printing a single line whcih contain the url and a transaction id .any one can help me to seprate both and to load the url with out printing it ?

Comment: Please post the code being used as well as the response received this will give us an idea of what is happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string functions (`preg_replace`, `str_replace`) to parse value you need.